# Firefox 63: wrong display of scrolled content

Tags: css, firefox

We develop a web application with Eclipse RAP with some views. After the last FF update to version 63 the content of the left view, which contains a tree widget, is displayed incorrectly. The content exceeds the view. Instead of being scrolled, the content is displayed outside the view. The horizontal scrollbar does nothing. It looks like there is something mixed up with the CSS overflow property.

Other browsers display the content correctly.

Does anyone know this bug?

Edit:

How to reproduce it:

1) Create any working minimal Eclipse RAP example, e.g. using an EntryPoint.
We are using Eclipse Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1) and RAP target 2.3.
I guess any newer versions of Eclipse or RAP will reproduce it as well.

2) Create some widgets. The bug appears in the org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label and org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree, maybe in others, too. org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text is fine, for example.

```
package raptest;
import org.eclipse.rap.rwt.application.AbstractEntryPoint;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem;

public class BasicEntryPoint extends AbstractEntryPoint {

@Override
protected void createContents(Composite parent) {
    parent.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    Label label = new Label(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    label.setLayoutData(new GridData(200, SWT.DEFAULT));
    label.setText("This is a very looooooooooooooooong text");

    Tree tree = new Tree(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    tree.setLayoutData(new GridData(200, 200));

    TreeItem treeItem;
    String txt = "Very loooooooooooooooong item ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        treeItem = new TreeItem (tree, SWT.NONE);
        treeItem.setText (txt + i);
    }

    Text text;

    text = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    text.setLayoutData(new GridData(200, SWT.DEFAULT));
    text.setText("This is a very looooooooooooooooong text");

    text = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    text.setLayoutData(new GridData(200, 200));

    text.setText("This is a very looooooooooooooooong text");
}
}
```

3) Start the RAP application in a browser

In Firefox 63 it looks like this (wrong):
[image: Widgets display wrong in FF63]

In Chromium it looks like this (correct):
[image: Widgets display correctly e.g. in Chromium (latest version)]

Maybe this problem is already solved in next Firefox versions.

Best, Julia

Comment: Does utilising the `white-space` CSS property help matters?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older versions of RAP use `-moz-scrollbars-horizontal` and `-moz-scrollbars-vertical`. `moz-scrollbars` is now deprecated. As of FF 63 you have to enable support in about:config (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#Deprecated)

Comment: No worries! I was investigating the exact same issue yesterday. Your question helped me solve the problem :)

Comment: A quick update on this issue: FF 66 removed support for `layout.css.overflow.moz-scrollbars.enabled` (See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1521399)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the wrong overflow behavior is the following:

With the inspection tools of the browsers I looked at the html elements that were generated by Eclipse for the example given in the question.

For the label widget, it generated two div elements: one for the border and one inside that for the text.

In chromium both of them have the css overflow hidden property.
In firefox only the inner div has this property, but in the outer one it is missing. If I add the overflow hidden property to the outer div element, the Label is displayed correctly.

It is still unclear to me, why the generated elements are different for different browsers. I start to believe, that the problem lies in the pretty old Eclipse and RAP versions that we use which are somehow not compatible to Firefox anymore.

Best, Julia

edit:

With Eclipse Photon and RAP 3.5 everything is displayed properly.